# Как правильно настроить роутинг в WEB API?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

Использую `ASP.NET MVC5 WEB API`

Есть конроллер:

```
public class StatsController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<StatsModel> Get()
    { }

    public float? Get(string university, string schoolType, string speciality, int year)
    { }

    public void Post([FromBody]StatsModel stat)
    { }

    public void Put(string university, string schoolType, string speciality, short year, [FromBody]StatsInOut newInOut)
    { }

    public void Delete(string university, string schoolType, string speciality, short year)
    { }
}
```

И роутинг:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "StatsApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{university}/{schoolType}/{speciality}/{year}",
defaults: new {university = RouteParameter.Optional, schoolType = RouteParameter.Optional, speciality = RouteParameter.Optional, year = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Проблема в том, что если запустить проект и перейти на вкладку API (где собирается документация по методам) куда-то пропали запросы GET (без параметров) и POST, доступны только следующие методы:

```
GET api/Stats/{university}/{schoolType}/{speciality}/{year} 
PUT api/Stats/{university}/{schoolType}/{speciality}/{year} 
DELETE api/Stats/{university}/{schoolType}/{speciality}/{year}
```

Но должны быть еще следующие:

```
GET api/Stats/
POST api/Stats/
```

Изначально все работало, но потом мне пришлось в каждый метод добавить переменную `speciality` и методы магическим образом пропали. Что я изменил не так - понять не могу, гугл ничего не дает.

Как вернуть потерянные методы?

Comment: Вам не нежно писать в роут конфиг такой сложный роут. Нужно просто api/{controller}/{id} или максимум api/{controller}/{action}/{id}. А параметры передавать или в body или в строке. Или есть специальные атрибуты [Route] у контроллера и методов

Comment: к сожалению мне нужен именно такой роутинг, т.к. в моей таблице 4х составной первичный ключ

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему добавив еще один роутинг:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "StatsApi2",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/",
defaults: new { university = RouteParameter.Optional, schoolType = RouteParameter.Optional, speciality = RouteParameter.Optional, year = RouteParameter.Optional }
```